# Angularjs, I can't pass variable to directive, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my template I call directory:

```html
<div ng-controller="ProfileController as vm">
  {{vm.profile._id}} <!-- test ok! _id printing -->
  <wcr-requestbutton receiving-id="vm.profile._id"></wcr-requestbutton>
</div>
```

In my directory I search receiving-id:

```js
function wcrRequestbutton() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/friendship/requestbutton/requestbutton.html',
    scope: {
      receivingId: '='
    },
    controller: requestBtnCtrl,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };

  return directive;
}
```

and in my controller I try use the receivingId varaible:

```js
function requestBtnCtrl(friendshipService){
    var vm=this;
    console.log('vm: ',vm); // console print: 'vm:  Object { receivingId: undefined }'
}
```

But when I launch demo, my console printing this result:
**vm:  Object { receivingId: undefined }**

Why? can help me?

Comment: Ofcourse these demo's won't work, you haven't even declared AngularJS..

Comment: Sorry, I have not explained. I launch Demo in my local machine with 'gulp serve', the app working.

Comment: Can you make a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2?p=catalogue) for us so we can help you?

Comment: struggling with the same problem, did you find a solution?